# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0

Tags: python, script, buffer

```
 line 1383, in <module>
    print(f.readline())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você está tentando ler arquivo tente algo como:

```py
open('file', encoding='utf-8')
open('file', encoding='latin1')
open('file', encoding='utf8')
open('file', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

E veja a lista complete de encoding em https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings